# Combobox Dropdown event triggers parent window Z index to change

Tags: wpf

I have a problem with a WPF business line application prototype that I do not know where to start to debug.

My Master Window (A) opens a "dialog" window using Dialog.Show(). The child window (B) has a combobox on it.

When the combobox is clicked (to expand and to show all the options) the entire second window (B) is hidden except the dropdownlist appearing from the combobox. The combobox isn't there, the window isn't there. Nothing is there except the dropdownlist and the master window behind it. If I click the master window then focus is once again set to window B and it shows as it should (because I set the Owner of window B to be window A).

To make it more interesting this bug is not consistent. It appears maybe 1 of 20 times I use the application, and when it starts appearing it can appear several times in a row and then stop happening again.

Possibly related is the fact that I think I have the same bug some times with MessageBoxes. When using MessageBox.Show()  (Win forms msgbox) from a viewmodel when only the master window (A) is showing the box occationally appears behind the master window making it invisible for the user.

My application is using GalaSoft MvvmLight (if that could have anything to do with it) and quite a few telerik components. Other than that I am not sure what data to provide. I don't think anyone can tell me the source of the problem based on this information, but where would you start looking for the problem?

Update : 
Good news! I have isolated the problem and found the combination of prerequisites for the phenomena to occur:
a) A  component showing a PDF file is currently open anywhere withing the application.
b) A telerik  component has been undocked and redocked.

I will include the code below, but I think the issue is buried deep within the RadDocking or WebBrowser component.

MainWindow

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OpenWindowClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var w = new TestWindow { Owner = this, DataContext = new TestViewModel()};
        w.Show();
    }
}

<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:telerikDocking="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls.Docking" 
    x:Class="TelerikGridDockingVsBrowserVsWindowBug.MainWindow"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="750" Width="925">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="200"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <telerikDocking:RadDocking Grid.Row="0">
        <telerikDocking:RadSplitContainer>
            <telerikDocking:RadPaneGroup>
                <telerikDocking:RadPane Header="I make bugs combined with a webbrowser showing a pdf document">
                    <TextBlock Text="1. Drag me and dock on the same or another location"/>
                </telerikDocking:RadPane>
            </telerikDocking:RadPaneGroup>
        </telerikDocking:RadSplitContainer>
    </telerikDocking:RadDocking>

    <Button Grid.Row="1" Click="OpenWindowClick" Content="2. Open window" Height="50" Margin="0,20"/>

    <WebBrowser Grid.Row="2" Source="http://www.kb.nl/sites/default/files/docs/pdf_guidelines.pdf"/>
</Grid>
```

TestWindow :

```
public partial class TestWindow : Window
{
    public TestWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

<Window x:Class="TelerikGridDockingVsBrowserVsWindowBug.TestWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="TestWindow" Height="150" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock> 3. Click on the combobox.</TextBlock>
    <ComboBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Options}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedOption}" Height="50"></ComboBox>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2"> This window will then disappear behind its owner</TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

TestWindow ViewModel:

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    public List<string> Options { get; set; }
    public string SelectedOption { get; set; }

    public TestViewModel()
    {
        Options = new List<string> { "String1", "String2" };
        SelectedOption = Options.First();
    }
}
```

I have an open ticket with Telerik about this, so I will update here if I find out anything.

Comment: I think your first step is playing around with it until you can consistently reproduce the bug. Put focus on different combinations of controls and see what happens. Once that happens, start putting breakpoints in, compare states of things, and post some code here if you need help.

Comment: Thanks Jim. See edits above :)

Answer (score 0):

I have been in your situation before... you have an unexplained problem... it doesn't make any sense... you've tried everything that you can think of... in a last ditch effort to fix the problem, you throw it out to all the experienced users here... then nothing... no responses... no help.

The thing is that if you can't find and fix the problem with all of your code right in front of you, then how can we fix it without any code?

All I can suggest is for you to try to locate exactly where the problem originates. You can do this by commenting out sections of code and then running your solution to see if that has removed the problem or whether it still exists. The fact that your problem only occurs infrequently will make this stage even more tricky.

However, with perseverance, you should be able to narrow down where the problem arises. Once you have managed to exclude enough of your code, the last step is to see if you re-create it in a much smaller new WPF project. If you manage to get to this stage, please come back and show your reduced code... *then*, we *may* be able to help you further.